# How to create a trigger to delete a record

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

Looking for ideas on how to write a trigger that will delete a record when a condition is met.

I have some records being written to a SQL Server 2008 database table. These records that are being written are not important and I would like to see them removed. There are two columns that will have unique information when these records are written and I would like a trigger to remove them as soon as they are written.

I could run a daily job to delete all records that equal X and Y but my thought why not delete the records as they are written.

What would this kind of trigger look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change that at any app layer you can use an [INSTEAD OF INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) trigger and those rows will not even be inserted at all.

It will save the database from both inserting and deleting.

Comment: Okay that makes sense doing a INSTEAD OF INSERT could you give me an example of what that trigger would look like?

Comment: There's a example at the link (that for the instead of insert documentation) above

Comment: thanks jean but it looks like the examples do not fit what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for help to write the trigger. I've never used triggers before so I don't know how this one should look. Can anyone help?

Comment: @user3407354 you should give a try and write trigger from the provided link in case you face any issues then post that we are here to help you to get out of problem we are not here to do your task.